# Redirecting only subpaths in vercel.json? (Next.js)

Tags: redirect, next.js, vercel

Changing the structure of my site and am trying to redirect everything behind `/blog` to `/`. So `/blog/some-blog-post` should now go to `/some-blog-post`. I am doing this:

```
    {
        "source": "/blog/:path*",
        "destination": "/:path*"
    },
```

This works.

However, I want to keep my blog overview page at `/blog`. This breaks now though? How can I redirect everything behind `blog` back to root, but keep `/blog`?

Comment: Does simply removing the star in the end of those patterns solve the issue?

Comment: thanks! trying this now, but will take some time since I can only test this by deploying to vercel.

Comment: Huh, does it not happen locally or why can't you test it locally?

Comment: the `vercel.json` file isn't applied locally, neither in dev nor when the project is built (unless I'm doing something wrong). I just pushed it to live though and your solution works!  Thanks a lot!

Comment: Oh right, I thought this was nextjs config redirects, should have read more carefully. I posted an answer so you can mark it as the solution if it worked. It was just a guess though :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should remove the star in the end of the path, since it probably makes the path slug optional, meaning that the rule also applies to just `/blog/` path as well.